# Finding the submatrix with the maximum sum

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Given an arbitrary \$N \times N\$ matrix, find the maximum sum submatrix. This particular approach uses the [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm). What could be improved both in terms of algorithm and code style?

```
def read_matrix_from_input():
    return [[int(s) for s in input().split(" ")] for row in range(int(input()))]


def max_subarray_sum(array):
    max_sum = current_sum = array[0]
    for number in array[1:]:
        current_sum = max(current_sum + number, number)
        max_sum = max(max_sum, current_sum)

    return max_sum


def max_submatrix_sum(row_major_matrix):
    column_major_matrix = list(map(list, zip(*row_major_matrix)))
    num_columns = len(column_major_matrix)
    num_rows = len(column_major_matrix[0])
    max_sum = column_major_matrix[0][0]

    for left_offset in range(num_columns):

        partial_sums = [0] * num_rows
        for right_column in column_major_matrix[left_offset:]:
            partial_sums = [partial_sums[row] + number for row, number in enumerate(right_column)]
            max_sum = max(max_sum, max_subarray_sum(partial_sums))

    return max_sum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(max_submatrix_sum(read_matrix_from_input()))
```